# Flash movie works fine during Control+Enter preview but does not work after publishing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I am trying to embed flowplayer into flash. I was able to succesfully do so and all the configuration settings worked fine when I was testing it using the control+enter preview. But after I published it to swf/html, the player doesn't work any more. I was following the lead from [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aflash.flowplayer.org/forum/1/10890#post-44115&oq=cache%3aflash.flowplayer.org/forum/1/10890#post-44115&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j61j60l2.3478&sugexp=chrome,mod=17&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) post. It would be great if anyone can help me out on this.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I am attaching the source files of my project. Please let me know if it works for you or if you can spot the error in the code.
dropbox.com/s/jn8dkzqu1w7px5n/flowplayer.rar

Comment: Probably you have a standalone player accessible, but no browser addon player installed. Otherwise, you need to be more specific.

Comment: I'm sure that it is a security error - loading from not trusted location - can you visit this [Settings Manager](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) site and add your location (folder) where your files are?

Comment: you really need to be running the debug player and tailing your log (check out vizzy).  it will make troubleshooting this and future issues much more painless

Comment: @Vesper i have browser player installed too

Comment: @dtudury no errors/warnings in the debugger either, works perfectly in debug mode

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela I think this is the issue, i am importing all the resources needed to load the player from my local machine. I have tried to work from localhost with no luck. I'll try to host everything on a live server and check. thanks

Comment: It didn't work even after uploading to server and by setting all flash permissions to "allow". I am sharing the source 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jn8dkzqu1w7px5n/flowplayer.rar
It has the fla and actionscript files. I have shared the file in the op also.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Part of the problem is solved. It is working in firefox after changing global security settings [here][1]. In the case of google chrome disabling pepper flash does the job. The problem that persists while running it on servers.

  [1]: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. Its working fine for me. Please follow some step to setup your development environment:

1. Install Debug Player and Non Debug Player for your  Browser
2. Then after publish your application using flash ide and in publish settings, html must be checked. (So you will get HTML file after published your application.)
3. Run HTML file which is generated by Flash IDE during publishing.

if still you are getting some error then you can check the settings manager configuration and you have to add your swf file.

In Last case you have to put your application in any local or public server and from there you have to run via html page which is generated during the publishing.